# Can gitlab runner copy source code into working folder and work on it there?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, pm2

My project is hosted on vps. Gitlab runner is in shell mode.

For this project I want to avoid dealing with ssh keys for deployment (pm2 deploy feature in particular) and at the same time I want source code to be available on server in easily accessible place (in case somebody else has to take over this project without access to my repository). So I imaging following workflow on ci pipeline. Is it possible?

1. Commit to mater branch
2. Gitlab runner pulls source code from repository into /work/dir/project.name (as if it is done manually by `git fetch && git pull`, but without having to have ssh key)
3. Environment variables from ci/cd settings are copied into .env file inside /work/dir/project.name (only old values or entire file replaced)
4. Gitlab runner executes `npm install && npm build` on this local code
5. Gitlab runner tells pm2 to execute ecosystem.config.js on this local code to restart app

If it is possible, then how exactly can this be done? If not possible or if there are better (and as easy or even easier) alternatives, then what can be done instead?